# How to save value of the new column in the "sales_flat_quote_item"?

Tags: magento-1.9, quoteitem

I created in the  installer a new column in "sales_flat_quote_item" named "comment". I set the value and it works but I can't save it in DB.

My piece of code:

```
$quote_item = Mage::getModel("sales/quote_item")->load(47);
$quote_item->setComment('test'); //field is set correctly.
$quote_item->save(); //but save don't work and my change gone.
```

Any idea how to save this value?

Comment: Are you adding custom comment box to each product in Cart?

Comment: Yes. In the quote every item has a field for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this post will help you to solve your issue.

http://magentocoder.jigneshpatel.co.in/magento-add-comment-box-to-each-product-in-cart/

OR

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378394/magento-adding-a-new-column-to-sales-flat-quote-item-and-sales-flat-order-item

Answer (score 0):

Ok from the link above I made it this way:

```
  $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
  $query = "UPDATE sales_flat_quote_item SET comment = '" .   itemNewValue['comment'] . "' where item_id = ". $itemNewValue['cartItemId'];
  $write->query($query);
```

today i found another solution. I think it's better beacuse we can avoid directly sql statement.

```
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
       if ($item['item_id'] === $itemNewValue['cartItemId']) {
           $item->setComment($itemNewValue['comment']);
           $item->save();
           }
    }
```